# retrieving image from sql server 2008 database using c#

Tags: c#, image

hi  i am trying to retrieve an image from sql server database using this code and the exception generate this error (parameter not valid) plz help me and i am using image type in the table not a blob

```
  SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(vsql, vCon);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(select);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("etudiant");
            byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];
            dp.Fill(ds,"etudiant");
            DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["etudiant"].Rows[0];
            MisDatos = (byte[])myRow["image"];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);
            System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: You would probably be better served by skipping the dataadapter and the dataset and retrieving it directly with a datareader.

Comment: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/190061).

Comment: can you plz modify this code and use datareader

Comment: I anticipate the problem is more likely due to the `image` field has a value that can't be displayed as an image.  The Image object can be used with a limited set of image types [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) says `The Image class enables you to load the following image types: .bmp, .gif, .ico, .jpg, .png, .wdp, and .tiff.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blob of code using datareader for a web page:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT photo,photomimetype,photofilename FROM MyTable WHERE id=@photoid", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@photoid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = photoId;
            using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = dr["photomimetype"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + dr["photofilename"] + "\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["photo"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 404;
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```